# Using numpy.append to mutate array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, append

I am working on tensorflow with MNIST database.

After extracting the database using the input_data.read_data_sets Function,

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
data = input_data.read_data_sets('data/MNIST/', one_hot=True)
```

I get data.train.images which is an array containing arrays of images.

I want to add my own image array onto this, as they are numpy arrays I cannot use the standard append function.

When I use the numpy.append() function, it creates a new array rather than mutate the existing one.

data.test.images is array of 55000 arrays each of 784(float32)values,

A is an array of 784(float32)values

The problem is when I try

```
data.train.images=np.append(data.train.images, [A],axis=0)
```

I get the error saying: " **can't set attribute** "

How do I get through this conundrum?

Comment: edit your qsn with what A has. i guess the issue is with [A].

Comment: The numpy.append documentary says that they need to have same  shape 

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

Comment: Nope, basically, i want the new data.train.images to have 55001 arrays with the last one being A

Comment: while we usually discourage the use of `np.append` (especially in loops), the `attribute error` suggests it has to do with assignment back to `data.train.images` rather than the append.  The usually debugging approach is to test the pieces of the problem line.  Does the append work by itself?  If so does the assignment work?  If not dig into the `data` structure.

Comment: @hpaulj: for my education, is it discouraged because it doesn't append in place?

Comment: New users often misuse it thinking it is just like the list append.  It returns a new array, so compared to list is relatively expensive.  It is just an alternative front end to `np.concatenate`.  It is better, in long run, to learn to adjust dimensions and use `np.concatenate` directly.  `concatenate` (and the the `stack` variants) take a list of arrays, not just 2.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, Like you said the problem is the assignment to the data.train.images. Went through the tensorflow source code, cant change the array. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy` + [`vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) instead:

```
a=np.array(np.random.rand(20,10))
b=np.array(np.random.rand(1,10))
a.shape
(20,10)
a=np.vstack([a,b])
a.shape
(21, 10)
```

Comment: I think the problem is that I am not able to update the data.train.images and not the append part